# how can i control whether two different accounts can call or not at the same time in selenium using Java?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid

I am doing a project and I am testing everything in a program like Skype. Through this program, we can do internet calls. I can't test whether two different accounts can call or not at the same time. I am using Selenium. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Why can't you? What is the problem you are facing to?

Comment: how can i send two different account address (like x@xx.com,y@xx.com) for testing the calls at the same time?

Comment: @htc           Selenium is a (resource expensive) tool to test the View tier of an application (normally, for various environments). The test that you suggest sounds very much like a functional/integration test. Perhaps you should reconsider where to place and how to run this test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create two instances of WebDriver:

```
WebDriver driver1 = new FirefoxDriver();
driver1.get("http://your-application");
WebDriver driver2 = new FirefoxDriver();
driver2.get("http://your-application");
// login with driver1 and driver2
```